# show me way to access the data from two tables

Tags: php, database

I have two erds show me best way to access data from tables i-e

The table one is Category and table second is Articles

```
TWO Tables ERD

 Table Category 

(CategoryId
CategoryName
CategoryDescription );

Table Articles 


(ArticlesId
 ArticlesTitle
 ArticlesBody
 ArticlesCreatedby
 CategoryId (`forigen Key`FK));
```

i dont have that Reputation to Post Pics, but here is the link of the picture of diagramatic ERD.

http://i341.photobucket.com/albums/o377/pakistanihaider/relation1_zps06c6e6ec.png

**OR**

The table one is Category and table second is Articles and third one is Category & Articles

```
Three Tables ERD

Table Category

(CategoryId
CategoryName
CategoryDescription );


Table  Articles

(ArticlesId
 ArticlesTitle
 ArticlesBody
 ArticlesCreatedby
    );

Table Category & Articles

(Category_id
Articles_id);
```

Also Diagramatic ERD of this Second Code:

http://i341.photobucket.com/albums/o377/pakistanihaider/relation_zpsea5d55a9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your data. If you only ever need one category per article, then option one will work. However if you might in the future require more than one category per article, your second option is better. The one thing you are missing is the second option, the Category & Articles table should have both fields as foreign keys.

The third table in the second option above is a joining table. It's express purpose is to provide the links between the other two tables. This allows a many to many relationship (a category can have many articles, and an article can have many categories), whereas the first option only provides a one to many relationship (each article can only have one category).

The reason both fields in the articles table should be foreign keys is because they will always relate to records in other tables. By setting them as foreign keys, you are protecting your data input (it will error if you try and enter and ID that is incorrect), and you are helping the database to optimise any queries you do joining the data.

Comment: Yes i am thinking of using Second ERD.

Sir, please explain about the suggestion which you gave me..
So you mean to say i should both category and articles id in third table as a foreign key?

Is it possible to use them as composite in third table??

Comment: I have updated my answer, hopefully it covers some more points. I'm not sure how much you know about the subject, but if you are not aware, you will be wanting to look at joining data. This will allow to combine data from several tables in one query, and return the combined dataset. This will be essential in either of your approches.